# How do I load a graph in neighborhood list format?

Tags: r, igraph

I have a file of neighborhood lists describing a directed graph:

```
1 2 5
2 4
```

which is equivalent to the edge list format:

```
1 2
1 5
2 4
```

How do I load it into igraph?

I can use [`read.lines`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/readLines.html) and [`strsplit`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strsplit.html) but I have a feeling that this has been done before by someone else.

Comment: Are spaces the only delimiters?

Comment: Actually, it's TABs. Each line describes the neighborhood of a single vertex.

Comment: So there's a tab between each element?

Comment: yes, `"1\t2\t5\n2\t4\n"`

Comment: How many rows are in your input file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are open to using a package still in development, I would suggest exploring the ["iotools"](https://github.com/s-u/iotools) package. It's file reader is *fast* (think along the lines of `fread` from "data.table") and it includes some splitting features. Use it in conjunction with `cSplit` from my "splitstackshape" package.

Here's a reproducible example with 1M rows:

First, a function to make some sample data:

```
data.maker <- function(size) {
  set.seed(1)
  lapply(seq_len(size), function(x) {
    as.character(c(x, sample(100, sample(20), TRUE)))
  })
}

x <- data.maker(1000000)
writeLines(vapply(x, paste, FUN.VALUE = character(1L), collapse = "\t"), "mytest.txt")
```

Second, load "dplyr" for piping, "iotools" for fast reading, and "splitstackshape" (which also loads "data.table") for splitting and aggregating.

```
library(dplyr)
library(iotools)
library(splitstackshape)
```

Here it is, all in one:

```
system.time({
  out <- input.file("mytest.txt", formatter = mstrsplit, sep = NA, nsep = "\t") %>%
    as.data.table(keep.rownames = TRUE) %>%
    cSplit("V1", "\t", "long") %>%
    .[, .N, by = .(rn, V1)]
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#  26.109   0.096  26.200
```

View of the output:

```
out
#               rn V1 N
#       1:       1 94 1
#       2:       1 22 1
#       3:       1 66 1
#       4:       1 13 1
#       5:       1 27 1
#      ---             
# 9865359: 1000000  1 1
# 9865360: 1000000 85 1
# 9865361: 1000000 91 1
# 9865362: 1000000 44 1
# 9865363: 1000000 20 1
summary(out)
#       rn                  V1              N        
#  Length:9865363     Min.   :  1.0   Min.   :1.000  
#  Class :character   1st Qu.: 25.0   1st Qu.:1.000  
#  Mode  :character   Median : 51.0   Median :1.000  
#                     Mean   : 50.5   Mean   :1.064  
#                     3rd Qu.: 75.0   3rd Qu.:1.000  
#                     Max.   :100.0   Max.   :5.000
```

---

If you prefer more standard packages, you can try the following. It should also be reasonably fast:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringi)
library(data.table)


temp <- stri_split_fixed(readLines("mytest.txt"), "\t", n = 2, simplify = TRUE) %>%
  as.data.table %>%
  .[, list(V2 = unlist(strsplit(V2, "\t", TRUE))), by = V1] %>%
  .[, .N, by = .(V1, V2)]
```